# Flow typing functions

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I want to get into the habit of properly flow typing everything. I have a few functions that I've typed such as below:

```
handleStartDateClick = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.setState({ selectDate: SELECT_DATE.START });
};

handleEndDateClick = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.setState({ selectDate: SELECT_DATE.END });
};
```

I'm a bit unsure what type for this function:

```
handleClearDates = (startDate, endDate) => (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  if (startDate || endDate) {
    this.props.client.writeData({
      data: {
        selectedDates: [],
      },
    });

    this.setState(() => ({
      selectDate: SELECT_DATE.START,
    }));
  } else {
    this.handleDayPickerClose();
  }
};
```

Any help/suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider asking in Flow's discord https://discord.gg/8ezwRUK

```js
handleClearDates = (startDate: Date, endDate: Date) => (event: SyntheticEvent<>) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  if (startDate || endDate) {
    this.props.client.writeData({
      data: {
        selectedDates: [],
      },
    });

    this.setState(() => ({
      selectDate: SELECT_DATE.START,
    }));
  } else {
    this.handleDayPickerClose();
  }
};
```

Comment: Could it also be `(event: SyntheticEvent<>): void ` ?